# specify floating point constant value bitwise in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, constants

This is what I am trying to do:

```
//Let Bin2Float be a magic macro that packages specified bit pattern into float as a constant

const float MyInf = Bin2Float(01111111,10000000,00000000,00000000);
```

We all know how to package the bit patterns into integers ("binary constant" hacks) and the input to this magic prototype macro is the same as would be for corresponding 32-bit integer binary constant macro. Packaging the bits into integer constant is not a problem. But, after playing with pointer and union punning, I realized that type-punning the integer into float, however, leads to many issues (some on MSVC side, some on gcc side). So here is the list of requirements:

1. Must compile under gcc (C mode), g++, MSVC (even if I have to use conditional compiling to do two separate versions)
2. Must compile for both C and C++
3. In resulting assembly code, must compile into hardcoded constant,
   not be dynamically computed
4. Must not use memcpy
5. Must not use static or global variables
6. Must not use the pointer-based type punning to avoid issues with
   strict aliasing

Comment: Put the bits into a `char buffer[sizeof(float)]`, result is `*((float*)&buffer[0])`. Aliasing through `char` is well-defined. Watch for endianness and alignment.

Comment: @GManNickG how different is that from using `union { char buffer[sizeof(float)]; float value; }`?

Comment: @GManNickG - that's not going to fulfil rule #3. I personally don't think this is a) desirable, and b) achievable. What would the point be? Why these exact 6 rules?

Comment: The old trick used in `Q_invSqrt()` technically works, but it invokes UB: `float f; unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)&f; ptr[0] = 0xff;`, etc.

Comment: @H2CO3 Since he's hard-coding the binary representation of a float, I doubt he's concerned too much about UB.

Comment: @OmriBarel None, except that version guarantees proper alignment. The takeaway from my comment was that aliasing through `char` is okay.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I dared suggesting this :) I just don't want to be talked off again by hair splitters.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's only UB if the resulting value is a trap value.

Answer (score 4):

First, there is rarely a need to specify floating-point constants in this way. For infinity, use `INFINITY`. For a NaN, use either `NAN` or `nanf(string)`. These are defined in `<math.h>`. The compiler is likely to compile `INFINITY` and `NAN` to some sort of assembly-language constant (could be in the read-only data section, could be formed in immediate fields of instructions, et cetera). However, this cannot be guaranteed except by the compiler implementors, since the C standard does not guarantee it. `nanf` is likely to result in a function call, although the compiler is free to optimize it to a constant, if the string is a constant. For finite numbers, use hexadecimal floating-point constants (e.g., “0x3.4p5”). The only IEEE 754 floating-point object you cannot completely specify this way, down the last bit, is NaNs. The `nan` and `nanf` functions are not fully specified by the C standard, so you do not have full control of the significand bits unless the implementation provides it.

I am unfamiliar with the binary constant hacks you allude to. Supposing you have a macro `Bin2Unsigned` that provides an `unsigned int`, then you can use this:

```
const float MyInf = (union { unsigned u; float f; }) { Bin2Unsigned(…) } .f;
```

That is, believe it or not, standard C syntax and semantics up to the point where the bits are reinterpreted as a float. Obviously, the interpretation of the bits depends on the implementation. However, the compound literal and reinterpreting through a union is specified by the C standard.

I tested with gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666), targeting x86_64, with -O3 and default options otherwise, and the resulting assembly code used a constant, `.long 2139095040`.

Comment: Is it specified through the standard? That breaks strict aliasing rules.

Comment: I think your suggestion doesn't meet point 1. As far as I know, MSVC doesn't support C99 at all, so a compound literal would make it barf. But who cares about MSVC anyway, +1.

Comment: @GManNickG: Please specify the rule you believe is violated. C 2011 6.5 7 says “An object shall have its stored value accessed only by… a type compatible with the effective type of the object… [or] an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members…”. Obviously, a `float` is compatible with a `float`, and the union has a `float` as one of its members. Additionally, note 95 points out that reading a different union member than the last-stored one, called type punning, causes reinterpretation of the bytes per 6.2.6.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You may be correct, but somebody else will have to address MSVC; I have no taste for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ah. Is that new in C11? Or am I just missing C99 know-how?

Comment: @GManNickG: In C 1999, 6.5.7 allows the same access with regard to unions. I do not find a note corresponding to C 2011’s note 95, but that is non-normative anyway. The fact that 6.5.7 allows access means the bytes have to be interpreted somehow.

Comment: On the other hand, C++11 says (9.5 Unions) *"In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time."*, which at least some of us interpret as allowing you to read only the member that was last assigned to. Anything else would be implementation specific, like when gcc explicilty allows type punning.

Comment: The C99 reference is footnote 82, which was added in TC3.