# Creating a NaN float value from the sign, exponent and mantissa parts in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, nan, bitset, mantissa

I need to create a floating point variable in C++ that has a NaN value. I also need to be able to see which NaN has a larger value. To compare the NaNs you will need to look at the mantissa part of the float. 
Creating a NaN using the standard

```
nanf("abc");
```

method results in NaNs with the same mantissa, even with different strings used in the nanf function. By creating the NaN from the basic parts of the bit pattern should prove to provide different mantissa's and therefore simple sorting can be performed on the size of the mantissa.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried decimal strings instead of "acb"? Or you could build the required bit pattern yourself. Since most implementations do, it might be acceptable to restrict the code you write to implementations that use IEEE floats. Just put the required pattern into an `uint32_t` and `memcpy` it into a `float` variable.

Comment: `nanf` is implementation defined - so the answer depends on your implementation. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio's to compile. I normally use g++ but i was getting so many errors it was easier to debug in VS. Ill try it in g++ and see what it returns. It may fix my issue.

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck with MSVC: "The input value is ignored" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn465173.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033267/specify-floating-point-constant-value-bitwise-in-c-c

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `frexp()` family of functions as well as `ldexp()`, which is kind of opposite to `frexp()`

Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ldexp/

Comment: Unfortunately you can't produce a NaN that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of type-punning floating-point values with unions and integer bitfields.

```
#include <iostream>

union floatPun {
    struct {
        unsigned int mantissa : 23;
        unsigned int exponent : 8;
        unsigned int sign     : 1;
    };
    float value;
};

union doublePun {
    struct {
        unsigned long long mantissa : 52;
        unsigned long long exponent : 11;
        unsigned long long sign     : 1;
    };
    float value;
};

template <typename PunT>
static int compare_mantissas(const PunT& a, const PunT& b) {
    return int(a.mantissa > b.mantissa) - (b.mantissa > a.mantissa);
}

int main() {
    floatPun fa = {0}, fb = {0};

    // make NaNs
    fa.exponent = fb.exponent = 0xff;
    fa.mantissa = 1;
    fb.mantissa = 2;
    std::cout << "fa: " << fa.value << "   fb: " << fb.value << "\n";

    // compare mantissas
    static const char* const cmp_labels[] = {"less than", "equal to", "greater than"}; 
    std::cout << "mantissa of fa is " 
        << cmp_labels[1 + compare_mantissas(fa, fb)]
        << " mantissa of fb\n";

    // change fa to +infinity
    fa.mantissa = 0;
    std::cout << "changed fa's mantissa to zero: " << fa.value << "\n";
}
```